# How to set wallpaper in Android

Tags: android, wallpaper

I am using Android SDK 1.6. Could someone tell me how to set an image as the wallpaper in the homescreen.

```
getApplicationContext().setWallpaper();
```

seems to be not working for me.

Comment: Although "getApplicationContext().setWallpaper();" works, it's not a good idea to use it because is deprecated. The best option nowadays is to use Wallpaper Manager

Answer (score 32):

You have to add the `SET_WALLPAPER` permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: XaB - please mark this topic "answered" so it goes off the "unanswered questions" list (and Cristian gets the points he deserves.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, the user that creates the question is not too experienced at using StackOverflow. It happens everyday. Bye!